# 400 Bad request in J2me

Tags: http, java-me, midp

I am trying to hit .svc service from my JME application using POST method. but getting 'bad request'. Following is my code.

```
HttpConnection hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-1.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0" );
hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+(postMsg.getBytes().length));

out = hc.openOutputStream();
out.write(postMsg.getBytes());

System.out.println("hc.getResponseCode() = "+hc.getResponseCode()+ "  hc.getResponseMessage() = "+hc.getResponseMessage());
```

Please tell me what is wrong with the code.

Comment: your code looks ok, it seems your GPRS is not working or your url is invalid. can you upload the url value ?

Comment: i am running the code through emulator hitting local ip. url is http://10.15.9.41:8002/WCFRetailAdaptor/Service.svc/GetLogin

Comment: is this url working in browser ?

Comment: If I hit till Service.svc it runs but if I hit entire till GetLogin, it gives 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. I tried using Get method, appending data to url, it works. but Post is not working. it gives bad request.

Comment: hi, I found other solution to send by using ksoap ..  its working..

Comment: ok good, then answer your self, so that it may guide to other users as well :)

Comment: The server response code can be some values, like the 400 and 500 level errors. Those are the most common ones to pop up in a browser window or response after the application request service. Verify the response description in log, but a think that the problem are "Request is incomplete for some reason." Normally the error level 400 is "There is a syntax error in the request. It is denied."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of http, I used Ksoap2-j2me-core jar with following code that i found -

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("namespace", "login");   

    request.addProperty("username", "pranav");   
    request.addProperty("password", "gangan");   


    //create the SOAP envelope   
    final SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);   
    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);   

    //create the transport and then call   
    final HttpTransport httpTransport = new HttpTransport("http://URL");   
    httpTransport.call("\"login\"", env);   

    SoapObject body = (SoapObject) env.bodyIn;   

    //body.getProperty(0) will return the content of the first tag inside body   
    Object response = body.getProperty(0);   
            System.out.println(response.toString);
```